# How can remove item in object from array localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I set my `localStorage` like bottom:

```
category: [
  {id: 1, name: "test_1"},
  {id: 101, name: "test_2"}
],
city: "",
country: "USA",
description: "",
options: {transactionType: "test", desOptions: "not found"},
phone: "",
title: ""
```

I want to remove `transactionType` or `desOptions` from `localStorage` if it's empty.

Do you have a solution or idea?

Comment: Nothing shown sets any localStorage and what is shown is not even a valid object

Comment: @charlietfl Why is it not a valid object?

Comment: @Run_Script would be valid if it was enclosed in `{}`

Comment: @charlietfl The asker probably just left out that part of the code, showing only the content of the object. The problem does not seem to be the whole object, just how to remove one item from it.

Comment: There is two `description` in this object. by the way, it is so simple. modify the object and re-write it to the `localStorage`.

Comment: @Run_Script Trying to point out to OP that the question is very incomplete and is not a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/**
* I am assuming that your storable
* object like:
*/
const store = {
    category: [
      {id: 2, name: "mashin"},
      {id: 102, name: "savari"}
    ],
    city: "",
    country: "Georgia",
    description: "",
    options: {transaction_type: "1", description: "not found"},
    phone: "",
    title: ""
};

localStorage = localStorage || window.localStorage;

// And you store the object into localStorage by JSON stringifying it.
localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(store));

// Get the stored item from localStorage. If nothing found then it's an empty object
let item = localStorage.getItem('store') || {};

if (!!item) {

    // Parse the JSON string into JSON object
    item = JSON.parse(item);

    // Check if the `options` object has empty values then remove them.
    item.options = Object.entries(item.options).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (!!v ? {...a, [k]: v} : a), {});

    // Finally store the updated store by stringifying it.
    localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(item));

}
```

Comment: work like a charm, tnx man `item.options = Object.entries(item.options).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (!!v ? {...a, [k]: v} : a), {});

    // Finally store the updated store by stringifying it.
    localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(item));`